# How to accept multiple types of barcodes when using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, avfoundation, qr-code, barcode

I am having trouble allowing several types of barcodes/QR codes when I am starting the AVFoundation, If I use one of them it works, but when I try to accept both it only accepts the last one

Here is the relevant code snippet

```
[captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]];
[captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code]
```

Is that now how I add several types to be accepted?

Comment: `[captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, nil];`? Or `[captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:@[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code]];`?

Comment: both worked like a charm, make it an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `setMetadataObjectTypes:`, it set the `metadataObjectTypes`, ie replace the previous value if there was one with the new one. It doesn't "add/sum" them.

So instead of using a `NSArray` with only one object (`[NSArray arrayWithObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]`), create an array with all the types you want, with `arrayWithObjects:` (notice the "s").

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, nil]`
```

With [short hand syntax](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) (it's equivalent):

```
@[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code]
```

Final:

```
[captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, nil];
```

or

```
[captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:@[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code]];
```